# Why can't gstat::krige accept duplicate locations when universal kriging?

Tags: r, kriging, gstat

Let us create a simple simulation worthy of `gstat::krige` with universal kriging, in the language of linear mixed models, i.e.:

[image]

Where `X` is a `n x n_vars` matrix of `n_vars` additional variables, `betas` is a `n_vars x 1` so-called fixed-effects vector, `Z` is a `n x q` indicator matrix of `q` locations, each repeating say `n / q` times, `e` is normal random noise from `N(0, sig2e)`, and `b` is a `q x 1` so-called random-effects vector, with a standard Gaussian `q x q` covariance matrix or kernel:

[image]

Where `d_i, d_j` are a pair of 2D `(lat, lon)` locations (there are `q` of these), and `sill` and `range` standard params.

In code:

```r
library(sp)
library(gstat)
library(MASS)

n <- 500 # no. of obs
n_j <- 5 # each loc repeats
n %% n_j == 0
q <- n / n_j # no. of unique locs
border <- 10
n_vars <- 3 # no. of additional X variables
sig2e <- 1 # random normal noise
sill <- 2
r <- 3 # range

# creating unique q coords in U(-border, border)
lat <- runif(q, -border, border)
lon <- runif(q, -border, border)
coords <- cbind(lat, lon)

# creating Gaussian covariance matrix, random effects and "Zb"
dist_mat <- as.matrix(dist(coords))
cov_mat <- sill * exp(-(dist_mat ** 2) / (r ** 2))
b <- mvrnorm(1, rep(0, q), cov_mat)
Zb <- rep(b, each = n_j)

# creating Xbeta, epsilon and finally y
X <- matrix(runif(n * n_vars), ncol = n_vars)
betas <- runif(n_vars, -10, 10) # all fixed effects are 1s
Xbeta <- 1 + X %*% betas # fixed part
e <- rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(sig2e)) # epsilon
y <- Xbeta + Zb + e

# creating final SP data frame
df <- data.frame(cbind(X, rep(lat, each = n_j), rep(lon, each = n_j), Zb, y))
colnames(df) <- c(paste0("X", 1:n_vars), "lat", "lon", "Zb", "y")
# df$lat <- df$lat + rnorm(n, sd = 0.001) # jitter, see later!
# df$lon <- df$lon + rnorm(n, sd = 0.001) # jitter, see later!
coordinates(df) <-  ~ lat + lon

head(df)
```

> ```
>                coordinates         X1        X2        X3          Zb          y
> X1   (0.3200503, -2.039568) 0.97051104 0.3845648 0.6642621 -0.51919361  1.1180234
> X1.1 (0.3200503, -2.039568) 0.33680328 0.6264120 0.6515018 -0.51919361  0.4308929
> X1.2 (0.3200503, -2.039568) 0.08526176 0.7651837 0.7296453 -0.51919361  3.5238127
> X1.3 (0.3200503, -2.039568) 0.21256636 0.8672858 0.4729741 -0.51919361 -1.8918401
> X1.4 (0.3200503, -2.039568) 0.06313677 0.3264258 0.2411893 -0.51919361  0.8680869
> X2    (9.717814, -3.006053) 0.41919020 0.5130563 0.8232494 -0.06774286  1.8317311
> ```

As can be seen, each location repeats `n_j` times (5 above), but that is Ok, the `X`s are different, random normal noise is added and the `y`s are different, as they should be.

Now, if we fit a variogram with a Gaussian kernel to these data, it gets the params pretty well, on say 80% of training data:

```r
# split to 80/20 training/testing
df <- df[sample(nrow(df)), ]
df_train <- df[1:floor(0.8 * n), ]
df_test <- df[(floor(0.8 * n) + 1):n, ]

# fitting variogram with Gaussian kernel
form <- as.formula(paste0("y ~ ", paste0(paste0(paste0("X", 1:n_vars), collapse = " + "))))
vgm_obj <- variogram(form, df_train)
fit_obj <- fit.variogram(vgm_obj, model = vgm("Gau"))

sig2e_est <- format(round(fit_obj$psill[1], 2), nsmall = 2)
sill_est <- format(round(fit_obj$psill[2], 2), nsmall = 2)
range_est <- format(round(fit_obj$range[2], 2), nsmall = 2)
cat(paste0("sig2e_est: ", sig2e_est, "\n",
           "sill_est: ", sill_est, "\n",
           "range_est: ", range_est, "\n"))
```

> ```
> sig2e_est: 1.00
> sill_est: 2.00
> range_est: 3.25
> ```

But! When trying to `krige()` to a testing set, we get `NA`s! (as reported [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/222192/192720), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/329290) and probably other places)

```r
y_pred <- krige(form, df_train, df_test, model = fit_obj)$var1.pred
head(y_pred)
```

> ```
> [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
> ```

The suggested solution is to dedup the locations but in this case it is of course totally wrong! What I currently do is add a small jitter to the locations, i.e. uncomment the above two lines of "jitter", in which case everything works great.

```r
# run everything only with these lines un-commented:
df$lat <- df$lat + rnorm(n, sd = 0.001) # jitter, see later!
df$lon <- df$lon + rnorm(n, sd = 0.001) # jitter, see later!

# ...

head(y_pred)
```

> ```
> [1] -0.934161  3.456668  3.231433 -2.689283  1.191044  1.431749
> ```

And you can see the fit is good:

```r
plot(df_test$y, y_pred, xlab = "y true", ylab = "y pred")
```

[image]

So bottom-line questions:

1. Why oh why, is this so? :) This is a standard use-case in universal kriging, is it not?
2. Am I missing something to make `gstat` behave this way? Should I handle the data differently to solve this?